# When to and not to create a new controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS so pardon my ignorance.

I have a page with dropdowns, textboxes and buttons within a controller say ControllerA. On button click I open a modal which has its own text boxes and buttons. Modal and the page are all in the same html.

**I would like to know when or what conditions are needed for me to think of creating a new controller?**

I mean should controllerA handle the modal's text box population and button click function or should I use a new controller for handling the modal?

Comment: in my opinions i'd ask my self. how big is the code of your modal? does it appears more times in your application? if both answers are yes, the create a new controller, if one is yes then maybe, if both are no then dont do it

Comment: Personally, I'd use a directive for the dialog box, which would have it's own controller.